# How to have multiple p tags in Onsen UI toolbar?

Tags: html, css, phonegap, onsen-ui

I am trying to add multiple lines of text, one below the other in an Onsen UI toolbar at the bottom on the page. However, when I try adding p tags, only the first one appears on the tool bar!

I have tried using css techniques like adding heights to onsen col inside the toolbar, etc. Although this places text side by side, when I use the 
 tag, the text disappears except first one again

```
<ons-toolbar style="background-image: none;" class="bottom_toolbar_div">

      <div style="background:green; color:white;" class="center toolbar__center toolbar__title" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif; width: 100%;">
       <ons-row>
            <ons-col  >

              <p class="tab-font-11">Payment mode </br> cod</p>
              <p>Change</p>
            </ons-col>


      </div>


    </ons-toolbar>
```

Ideally "payment mode" must come first and below it "cod" then "change"

Answer (score 0):

Onsen UI applies `navigation-bar__title` class to `div` inside `ons-toolbar`. This class describes the following style:

```css
.navigation-bar__title {
    line-height: 44px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1f1f21;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

The reason why you see only first line of the text is `line-height`. They set it equal to the height of the toolbar. So, everything below the first line of the text is actually rendered, but outside the toolbar.

Create your own class and set `line-height` equal to your `font-size`. Also set margin for `p` so that fit into 44px of the height of the toolbar

```css
.myClass {
    line-height: 11px !important;
    font-size: 11px !important;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Use your class on the page:

```html
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center myClass">
      <p>Payment mode <br> cod</p>
      <p>Change</p>
    </div>
  </ons-toolbar>
</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a closing `</ons-row>`